# keep the scroll bar at the bottom but only for once not in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a chat app that show the previous messages by fetching the datas repeatedly using setInterval(). So as most of the chatting apps do, I also want to keep the scroll bar at the last message(i.e at the bottom). But here comes the problem ,as I am using setInterval to fetch The data repeatedly it also execute that code which keep the scroll bar at the bottom and hence it become impossible to scroll up to check the previous messages.

```
<script>
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
      //fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#messages").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      //chatTimer = setTimeout(fetch_chat, 500); //request the chat again in 2 seconds time
      $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");


    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
 fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    //immediately fetch chat for the new ID, and clear any waiting fetch timer that might be pending
    //clearTimeout(chatTimer);
    fetch_chat(); 
  });

  function scrollToBottom() {
    $("#messages").scrollTop(1e10); // Lazy hack
}

setInterval(function() {
    fetch_chat();
}, 500);

  $("#sub").click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val();

    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
      scrollToBottom();
    });
  //  alert(text);
  });

  //this will also trigger the first fetch_chat once it completes
});
</script>
```

plz tell me the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable outside the setInterval method that sets if it is the first time that the data is fetched. Scroll only the first time. Then, change it and it will never scroll again.

```
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;
var firstTime = true;

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
      //fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#messages").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      //chatTimer = setTimeout(fetch_chat, 500); //request the chat again in 2 seconds time
      if (firstTime) {
          firstTime = false;
          $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
      }
    }

  });

}
```

Comment: it doesnt work and rather the scroll bar remain at top instead of bottom